# How to check all the post data sended by your web-browser in a form on a web page?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, post, developer-tools

Is there any way to know what data are you sending in a post request?, i mean all of it?

I want to know this specificaly from a web-browser, doesn't matter which one in particular meanwhile can be installed on windows.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by intercepting the request you send with a proxy (ex: BurpSuite).

See https://www.adampalmer.me/iodigitalsec/2014/12/03/burpsuite-intercepting-modifying-http-requests-responses/

Basically you need to put your browser proxy to 127.0.0.1:8080, launch burp and start the intercept mode in the proxy tab.